# Can you hook into an interface-less jar?

Tags: java, api

Is it possible to run a function upon a function call in an interface-less import?If I'm importing a library, as an example, is it possible that each time its function foo is called, my function, bar, will be called as well?
Thanks

Comment: Is it called by your code? Can you perhaps modify your code to use a different class that extends the class with `foo(`?

Comment: You can subclass and override their function foo to call bar, then make your subclass ubiquitous enough...

Comment: Oh, and post all of your code. We might be able to find some problems other than what you are talking about. We also want to know what this is for.

Comment: Hard to know exactly what you're asking, but you might be able to use [cglib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) to create a proxy that runs your code before/after the target method.

Comment: @tbodt Not all of the code, just the relevant portions.

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit your code and the class that `foo` resides in is non-final, you can override the class's `foo` to call `bar` as well:

```
class MyFooClass extends FooClass{
    @Override
    void foo(){
        bar(); //Not sure if you want bar to be static or not, or if you want bar first or last.
        super.foo(); 
    }
}
```

Then simply use `MyFooClass` instead of `FooClass` throughout your code.